# Using CCDelay Time in a loop

Tags: objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone, delay

I have 6 menu items on my screen that I want to slide off the screen one by one after the help button (one of the 6 items) is clicked. Here's my code:

```
NSArray * menuArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, item2, item3, item4, item6, item5, nil];
CCDelayTime * delayM = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1.4];
for (CCMenuItem * item in menuArray) {
    id moveLeft = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.7 position:ccp(10, 0)];
    id moveRight = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.4 position:ccp(-200, 0)];
    //CCDelayTime * delayM = [[CCDelayTime alloc] initWithDuration:1.4];
    [item runAction:[CCSequence actions:moveLeft, moveRight, delayM, nil]];
}
```

For some reason, the delay doesn't seem to make any difference here and all of the menu items slide off the screen at the same time. How can I make it so that the menu items won't slide off the screen until the last one already has?

Sidenote: I can't figure out how to cancel all of the selectors that these menu items are hooked up to so that the user won't accidentally touch a selector while this whole animation is going on. Could someone help me with this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because they all start those actions at the same time.

This is how you might do it:

```
NSArray * menuArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, item2, item3, item4, item6, item5, nil];
float delay = 0;
for (CCMenuItem * item in menuArray) {
    CCDelayTime * delayM = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:delay];
    id moveLeft = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.7 position:ccp(10, 0)];
    id moveRight = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.4 position:ccp(-200, 0)];
    [item runAction:[CCSequence actions:delayM,moveLeft, moveRight,  nil]];
    delay += 1.1;
}
```

Remember, the runAction is asynchronous - so to make them do it one by one, you have to start with no delay, and for each item, add to the delay the length of time it will take for the previous item's actions. In this case, every item's actions take 1.1 seconds (.7 for the move left, and .4 for the move right), so we extend the delay-before-movement by 1.1 seconds every item.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to cancel the selectors that the ccmenuitems correspond to?

Comment: You can't really 'cancel' the ccmenuitem selectors without having to re-add them. What you can do is keep track of the sequence (eg, id sequence = [item runAction:[CCSequence....]]; and then in the method fired by the button, add a check for: if(sequence == nil || [sequence isDone]) { ... method stuff ... }

Comment: well i mean that the items i have that are being moved right are hooked up to selectors at the moment, but I want to unschedule those selectors so the user can't tap them while the actions are taking place. Is that possible? I tried [item unscheduleAllSelectors] but that didn't do anything.

Comment: You can disable the CCMenuItem by doing [item setIsEnabled:NO], although if I recall this may change the appearance of the item depending on how you've set up it various states. A third (and really easy) option is to have a boolean flag somewhere BOOL _isInMotion that you set to YES when you start moving all of the menu items, and then do a **if(_isInMotion) return;** in your selector - although that is basically the same as my previous suggestion.

Comment: ya it turns them gray from black. any other options?

Comment: Well, you can set it so that the disabled state looks exactly like the on state, or you can subclass (or category) CCMenuItem with something like removeAction - look a the source code, you'll probably want to do something with the *invocation* ivar, or add a 'canActivate' flag and override 'activate'. There are lots of ways to do it, you just have to dig around.